# Window not able to maximize until manual dimension adjustment

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have an application that starts up with a main window that I've customized using `WindowStyle="None"`. Because of this I've needed to reimplement the maximize/minimize button in the titlebar.

After doing so, however, I've discovered that the window will not maximize to fill the entire screen. Rather it only fills a space equal to it's current size after getting 'docked' in the top left corner. I then discovered that I can get the window to maximize correctly, if I adjust the dimensions in any way whatsoever (in fact, merely clicking on the edge of the window does the trick).

Does anyone know how I can get my window to maximize correctly without making a manual adjustment to its dimensions?

Here's my main window's xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="MainWindow" Name="MainWindowName"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:c" UseLayoutRounding="True" 
        mc:Ignorable="d" TextOptions.TextFormattingMode="Display" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight" 
        Title="Application" MinHeight="700" MinWidth="1200" WindowStyle="None" >
```

And my maximize button is just this:

```
            if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
            }
            else
            {
                this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
            }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove `SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight"`

If you need to retain the above property, since you only really need it when the window is not maximized:

```
if (this.WindowState == WindowState.Maximized)
{
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.WidthAndHeight;
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Normal;
}
else
{
    this.SizeToContent = SizeToContent.Manual;
    this.WindowState = WindowState.Maximized;
}
```

Comment: Awesome! This definitely works, but is there any way for me to retain the property without introducing the maximizing bug?

Comment: added in the answer's body

Comment: I updated the answer again to change the order, since you first need to set SizeToContent

Comment: Perfect. Thanks a lot for the help! I should also mention that I added the above logic to some other fancy methods that handle maximizations from and restorings that are initiated from the start-bar.